# Setting content type for node JS http request

Tags: node.js, http

I'm developing a simple app with Node.js to act as an orchestration layer to intercept requests and send them to another app running in parallel (My intermediate app will sit on port 8000 and intercept requests via an API `/interceptMessage` and then route the request to another API running locally in a different app on port 5000 `/processMessage`).  I have the whole app set up, but I'm running into issues calling the second app via an http POST request.  Here is my Controller.js code:

```
exports.postToClient = function(req, res) {
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5000,
  path: '/processMessage',
  method: 'POST',
  accept: 'application/json',
  //For testing, will use the request's JSON eventually
  json: {
    "message":"Hello"
  }
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(options));
http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
}).end();
}
```

When I hit my intermediate app via Postman, I get the following error message from flask `data = request.json['message']\nTypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`.  From digging around, it seems like the issue is that when I send the request, the content type isn't set, but anytime I try to set the content type in my options header I get a build failure.  How would I set the content type for my request so it uses 'application/json', or is that not even my problem?

Comment: I'd suggest you look at the sample code for `http.request()` [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_url_options_callback) when doing a POST . It doesn't look to me like you're doing it correctly. You're missing the `req.write(postData)`.

Comment: Actually, your link led me to my answer for that, I just needed the `headers` option to set the content-type.  Now I'm getting a 400 error, but it's different :)

Comment: Or, alternatively, use the [request library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) which is much simpler to use than `http.request()`.

Comment: A 400 error (which is Bad Request) could very well be because you didn't send the post body with `req.write(postData)` like you're supposed to as I pointed out earlier.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'll try it this way, thanks!

Comment: @jfriend00 you were absolutely right, I needed to write to the request object.  It's working! If you post this as an answer I will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write to the request object to send your POST data:

```
exports.postToClient = function(req, res) {
    var http = require('http');

    var options = {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 5000,
      path: '/processMessage',
      method: 'POST',
      accept: 'application/json',
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(options));
    let req = http.request(options, function(res) {
      console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
      console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
      });
    });
    req.on('error', (e) => {
        console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
    });
    req.write(/* properly formatted/encoded post data here */);
    req.end();
}
```